# App to encrypt and store all my photos online?

Tags: encryption, iphone-app, privacy, photography

I don't like the idea that Google employees can view my private pictures.  Is there a good app to encrypt and store all my photos in Dropbox or Google Drive?

Comment: If your concerned about your privacy then why you uploads photos to  `Dropbox` or `Google Drive`, use iCloud to store photos else third party apps like `SpiderOak`(which encrypt files and upload to it's server)

Comment: iCloud has the same problem - the employees at Apple can view my files.  SpiderOak looks OK, but can I trust them to keep my precious data secure for the next 20 years?  I trust Google more.

Comment: take a look on my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**boxcryptor**](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/home)

Boxcryptor protects your files in the cloud no matter if you use Dropbox, Google Drive, Microsoft OneDrive, SugarSync, Box.net, or any other major cloud storage provider. It also supports all the clouds that use the WebDAV standard such as Cubby, Strato HiDrive, and ownCloud.

Boxcryptor have **free/paid** versions.It works on all major platforms including computers/mobiles, just see the [download](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/download) for more details

Comment: Hint: Boxcryptor is also [available for Android](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boxcryptor2.android), and all the other "major platforms" (even on your desktop computer, see [the download page](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/download)). So using this, you will "stay fine" even when using a different platform e.g. with your secondary device. Note however that if you need more than the "basic features", *Boxcryptor* has a yearly subscription fee of EUR 36/72.

Comment: @Izzy OP need the details regarding `iPhone/iOS` and din mentioned that he need a free/paid service, that's why I din detailed my asnwer

Comment: I wasn't critisizing at all (even upvoted ;) – just thought the additional details might be useful also for other visitors.

Comment: @Izzy I know Brother :)

Answer (score 1):

In regards of security, [Nordlocker](https://nordlocker.com) is a good solution for file encryption with high privacy focus as well. It protects files with easy encryption process (drag and drop into the locker). Only you and people with password can access them.

It has a free option, which allows to encrypt up to 5gb of data for free. I started from this version three months ago and I sticked to it (now I pay less than 3 $ monthly). A straightforward interface makes it very easy to know how to setup and use it. Worth every penny.

Actually, I'm satisfied with the feature to keep files on my computer, however, application is compatible with any cloud storage provider.